# Replace fluorescent lights with LED lights

Tags: fluorescent

Can I replace fluorescent lights (30W, 36" long - F30T12 H998) with LED lights?

Comment: Yes you can.   anything else ??  NOT enough info. What led lights? replace the whole fixture ?  Please add ALL  the details.

Comment: they even make retrofit tubes, or you can replace the ballast with an LED driver and use LED strips.

Answer (score 1):

I searched f30t12 LED replacement, the first lamp that came up is a 3’ t8 lamp 13w 5000k for $6.88. These are plug-and-play, you swap the t8 lamp in and they work with the ballast. (A t12 lamp and t8 lamp use the same size tombstone)  So yes there is an easy one and there may be direct wire out there that bypasses the ballast, but 3’ lamps are less common so there may not be as many choices but these did state 120-277v. I just did not look further, the vendor was 1000bulbs.Com I use them for some of my lighting, and I like DLC certified lamps as these have a 5 year warranty.

Comment: I have used 1000bulbs.com a few times - highly recommended.

Comment: I really hate my fluorescent bulbs... will definitely have to give them a go for LED replacements!